# Why fscanf in c reads csv files wrong?

Tags: c, csv, file, txt

I am making a linked list of World Cup teams, when loading the teams I need to do a preload reading data from a **csv** file but reading 2-word countries makes it wrong

For example

Suppose that this is the **csv** file:

```
Arabia Saudita, Herve, Renard, Salman, C, 0, 1
```

First I read the country name, dt name, captain name, group and two numeric values that are part of the program, but the output is something like this:

```
Country:Arabia DT:Saudita Herve Renard Salman C 0 1 Captain: empty Group:Empty
```

The expected output would be

> Country: Arabia Saudita DtName:Herve DtSurname:Renard CaptainName:Salman Group: C

I tried to do it with a txt file but it is the same since it reads the spaces and the program fails or prints wrong

This is a part of the code that fails

```
    FILE *chargue = fopen("Precharge.csv", "r");
    
    while (!feof(charge)) {
        fscanf(charge, "%s\n", countryAux);
        chargecountry(&team, countryAux);
    
        fscanf(charge, "%s\n", nameDTAux);
        fscanf(charge, "%s\n", surnameDTAux);
        chargenameDT(&team, surnameDTAux, nameDTAux);
    
        chargeCapitan(&team, nameCapaux);
    
        fscanf(charge, "%c\n", &groupAux);
        chargegropu(&team, groupAux);
    
        fscanf(charge, "%d\n", &actualscoreaux);
        chargeactualscore(&team, actualscoreaux);
    
        fscanf(charge, "%d\n", &faseActualaux);
        chargeFase(&team, faseActualaux);
    
        insert(lis, team);
        forwards(lis);
    }
```

Comment: Look at your format string.  What character do you say should be after the field that you read in?

Comment: Not your major problem, but: [Why is `while( !feof(file) )` always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941)

Comment: after reading the char it should show Group:A

Comment: feof is wrong  - you must read something before you call feof. also you must check the return status of all read functions, and deal with any errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format strings parse single words and do not stop at the `,` separator.

Parsing the **csv** file (or any file in general) with `fscanf()` is not recommended as it is very difficult to recover from errors and newlines are mostly indistinguishable from other white space characters. Furthermore, it is incorrect to use `while (!feof(charge))` to run this loop.

You can learn [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong?rq=1) and you should tell you teacher about this. It is a common mistake to use `feof()` for this pupose.

You should instead read one line at a time with `fgets()` and use `%nnn[^,]` conversion specifiers to parse the character fields (`nnn` being the maximum field length).

Here is an example:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char buf[256];
    char countryAux[100];
    char nameDTAux[100];
    char surnameDTAux[100];
    char groupAux;
    int actualscoreaux, faseActualaux;
    ... // declare team, lis...

    FILE *chargue = fopen("Precharge.csv", "r");
    if (chargue == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", "Precharge.csv",
                strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, chargue)) {
        if (sscanf(buf, "%99[^,],%99[^,],%99[^,], %c ,%d ,%d",
                   countryAux, nameDTAux, surnameDTAux,
                   &groupAux, &actualscoreaux,&faseActualaux) == 6) {
            chargecountry(&team, countryAux);
            chargenameDT(&team, surnameDTAux, nameDTAux);
            chargeCapitan(&team, nameCapaux);
            chargegropu(&team, groupAux);
            chargeactualscore(&team, actualscoreaux);
            chargeFase(&team, faseActualaux);
            insert(lis, team);
            forwards(lis);
        } else {
            printf("invalid record: %s", buf);
        }
    }
    fclose(chargue);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that while(!feof) was wrong, that's the way they taught us in college,thanks

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: of course! unless the destination array has a length at least as great as the source string.

Comment: Nice.  Minor: `"\n"` at the end of `sscanf(buf, "%99[^,],%99[^,],%99[^,], %c ,%d,%d\n"` does little.  Perhaps `char junk; sscanf(buf, "%99[^,],%99[^,],%99[^,], %c ,%d, %d %c", .... &junk) == 6)` ?

Comment: @Kalifeh: I amended the answer with a link to an explanation regarding this mistake. They should not teach this in your college, try and point them to the reasons

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: `chargegropu` is probably a typo, but consistent with the question.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: the trailing `\n` is a mistake and your suggestion is welcome if records with extra fields are to be rejected.  The space before `%d` is redundant but might be useful before the `,`.